# How to use SetProgressValue in Flutter

Tags: flutter, winapi, interop, ffi

I'm trying to us [`ITaskbarList3::SetProgressValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-itaskbarlist3-setprogressvalue) in my Flutter App like this:

Get the `hWnd` (thanks to [Kirill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68162870/995926)):

```dart
final user32 = DynamicLibrary.open('user32.dll');
final findWindowA = user32.lookupFunction<
   Int32 Function(Pointer<Utf8> lpClassName, Pointer<Utf8> lpWindowName),
   int Function(Pointer<Utf8> lpClassName, Pointer<Utf8> lpWindowName)>('FindWindowA');

final hWnd = findWindowA('FLUTTER_RUNNER_WIN32_WINDOW'.toNativeUtf8(), nullptr);
print(hWnd);
```

And my try to use the API:

```dart
final explorerframe = DynamicLibrary.open('Explorerframe.dll');
final setProgressValue = explorerframe.lookupFunction<
    Int32 Function(Int32 hwnd, Uint64 ullCompleted, Uint64 ullTotal),
    int Function(int hwnd, int ullCompleted, int ullTotal)>('SetProgressValue');

setProgressValue(hWnd, 50, 100);
```

However I get the error:

> Invalid argument(s): Failed to lookup symbol 'SetProgressValue': error code 127

To be honest I do not understand what I'm doing wrong. I was currios which functions are exposed by that dll file I get found out: Nothing

[image]

Should that functions not be exported here?

Comment: COM interface method implementations aren't exported by modules. Instead, the implementing module exports a single class factory (`DllGetClassObject`) that returns an interface pointer. Once you have an interface pointer you can start calling methods on it, as long as the programming language in use can call functions through function pointers.

Comment: Ah that means that I cannot use the FFI package? Do you know how I can do it in Flutter or do I need to implement that in C++ directly?

Comment: You may be able to use the [win32](https://pub.dev/packages/win32) package. There's also a package specifically targeting the [windows_taskbar](https://github.com/alexmercerind/windows_taskbar) on GitHub. I cannot comment on the quality of either.

Comment: Thank you I'll check that package. If you would put this in an answer I would be already happy enough to accept it.